# How to get children of root node in Firebase for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following tree structure

[[image: 1]]

I need to get the information Name and Details alone and their children.

I have done this, but doesn't run and shuts down the application when executed:

```
info = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        info.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot infoSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, infoSnapshot.child(info.toString()).getValue(String.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the data from the root node, please use the code below:

```
info = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
info.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String child = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", child);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

The output will be:

```
details
name
```

Comment: Alex - Thank you. But I need only "name" and "details". Not their children. Is there a way to get only that?
Basically, I need the children of the root (myapplicationone-f0887) and not their children.

Comment: hey how do i use it for getValue

Comment: @Player91 I'm not sure I understand. I think that best it will be add a new question, here on Stackoverflow, so I and other Firebase developers can take a look at it.

Comment: @AlexMamo   What should I do if I'm using a model class, please can u check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562000/not-getting-data-from-direct-child-of-root-node-in-firebase

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the data snapshot, then you can easily iterate through all the data received..

```
info = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    info.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot infoSnapshot:dataSnapshot.child("details").getChildren()) {
                Log.i(TAG, infoSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }
            for(DataSnapshot infoSnapshot:dataSnapshot.child("name").getChildren()){
                Log.i(TAG, infoSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Comment: This gives me the details of the children of the root. Is there a way to get the children of the root? (Name and Details, not the children of Name and Details)

Comment: Then you can directly use dataSnapshot.getChildren() to get the children of the root and then use it's value. One thing you can do is examine the whole datasnapshot by printing it's String value.. then you can access any child member of the datasnapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line is useless :

```
mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

and change this like

```
info = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(mDatabase.toString());
```

to

```
info = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

also this:

```
Log.i(TAG, infoSnapshot.child("root").getValue(String.class));// the root node doesn't exists
```

Comment: Thanks made the changes

Comment: Nope. Still shut down on running the project

Comment: add your logcat