# Not getting data from direct child of root node in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

becuase of some reaon i deleted the parent node and make all the child node direct under the root node

but when im getting refrence of the root node im unable to the child data

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        model = new Model();
        quotes_list = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    model = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model.class);
                    if (model != null) {
                        quotes_list.add(model.getTitle());
                        position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
                        Log.d(TAG, quotes_list.toString());

                    }
                }
                quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
                countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
                Log.d(TAG, quotes_list.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

Comment: "I'm unable to" is really hard to help with. What *does* happen when you run this code in a debugger, and what did you expect to happen? Is your `onDataChange` gettin called at all? If not, is the `onCancelled` getting called instead?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  i was expecting to get the quotes from the firebase and show it as text, here is the json https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7T7TwfvcBhl8eg8FoBFoZU984xi-MPH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I understand what you expect, but that doesn't answer the questions in my first comment though. Does you `onDataChange` get called? If not, does your `onCancelled` get called. With such basic debugging information, it is much more likely that someone here can spot what is going wrong.

Comment: okay i check in logcat but its showing null , here is how i get Log.d("TAG", quotes_list.toString());

Comment: I think you're missing the point of @FrankvanPuffelen. The first thing I want to ask if if you're returning quotes_list before the call back is even excuted which could be why you're getting null. Add two breakpoints one to on data changed and one to onCanclled so you know what is called when firebase returns data to you

Comment: @OlayiwolaOsho can u have a look here https://codeshare.io/BAlx3n

Comment: Could you confirm that your Firebase Security Rules gives your client app access to read its data and confirm that you actually have some data in your root node @Player91

Comment: yes the read is true